# Changing the color of each column in high charts

Tags: highcharts

I am working on high charts api.I want to display each column a different color how it is possible. Below is the code and screen shot of chart
[image: Chart screen shot]

In this image it is showing black for every column but i want different color in each. I give an array of color but it is picking the first one only

```
$(function () {
    $('#pak_med').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },      
         colors: ['#000000', '#0066FF', '#00CCFF'],

        title: {
            text:  [ <?php 
    $query = mysqli_query($connection," select distinct d ,med, c,country_name from
        (select date_format(apdate,'%Y') as d,doc_country as country_name,
        med,count(med) as  c from view_doc_prescriptions where doc_countryId={$_GET['country']} group by med, d)f 
         group by d order by d desc ;

") or die("date created error"); 
//$total=0;
$info = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

//  echo $info['spec'];
    echo "'";
    echo "Top Medicine in ".$info['country_name'];
    echo "'";
    echo ',';

?>]
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [ <?php 
    $query = mysqli_query($connection," select distinct d ,med, c,country_name from
        (select date_format(apdate,'%Y') as d,doc_country as country_name,
        med,count(med) as  c from view_doc_prescriptions where doc_countryId={$_GET['country']} group by med, d)f 
         group by d order by d desc ;

") or die("date created error"); 
//$total=0;
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
//  echo $info['spec'];
    echo "'";
    echo $info['d'];
    echo " ";
    echo $info['med'];
    echo "'";
    //echo $info['spec'];
    echo ',';
}
?>]
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Top Medicine',
            data: [     <?php 
    $query = mysqli_query($connection," select distinct d ,med, c,country_name from
        (select date_format(apdate,'%Y') as d,doc_country as country_name,
        med,count(med) as  c from view_doc_prescriptions where doc_countryId={$_GET['country']} group by med, d)f 
        group by d order by d desc;

") or die("date created error"); 
//$total=0;
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
//  echo $info['spec'];
    echo $info['c'];
    //echo $info['spec'];
    echo ',';
}
?>]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.colorByPoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line

```
series:[{
colorByPoint: true,
}]
```